# gunicorn working vs uwsgi timeout

Tags: centos, python, django, uwsgi, gunicorn

I've setup my Python / Django app on a vmware machine with CentOS, uwsgi and gunicorn along with all my apps dependencies.

After running my app with gunicorn with the following command:

```
gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:8081 wsgi:application
```

The application works like a charm and everything is going smoothly. However, i tried running it with uwsgi to compare performance (requests / second) on both. So i ran the following command:

```
sudo uwsgi --chdir=/var/www/pyapp/ --module=wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings --socket=127.0.0.1:8081 --processes=5  --harakiri=20  --max-requests=5000  --vacuum --master --pidfile=/tmp/pyapp-master.pid
```

The first problem i encountered running this is the following error:

```
invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096)...skip
```

After adding the -b 25000 to make the buffer larger than the maxmimum, i started encountering:

```
timeout. skip request.
```

I couldn't suspect that my app had something wrong with it as it ran with gunicorn without such problems.

Can someone help pointing out what i am doing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding --protocol=http solved the problem. By default uwsgi works with wsgi protocol which doesn't accept http requests.

In addition, instead of using the reverse proxy, you have to use uwsgi mode

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name apps.myapp.com apps-backend.myapp.com;

    root /www/python/apps/myapp/;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/apps.myapp.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/apps.myapp.com.error.log;

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production
    location /static/ {
        alias /www/python/apps/myapp/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /www/python/apps/myapp/media/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass myapp;
        include uwsgi_params;
#        proxy_pass_header Server;
#        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
#        proxy_redirect off;
#        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
#        proxy_connect_timeout 50;
#        proxy_read_timeout 50;
#        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
    }

    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. If you solved this problem, please mark it as solved by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer, so that it turns green.